# Is $\sin \cos \tan \cos \sin x = {\rm constant}$ for any value of $x$?

Tags: trigonometry

While using a calculator I found out that ($\sin \cos \tan \cos \sin x = k$), where $k$ is a constant ($< 1$)  for any value of $x$, but I couldn't prove it. Is this a correct identity? If yes, then how to prove it? Any helpful hints to proceed are also welcome.

Comment: Especially if you're working in degrees, then $\sin(x)$ will be a very small number. $\cos(x)$ if x is very small will be about $1$. Then $\tan(x)$ will take it's final value depending on whether or not you're working in degrees or radians. There is no identity here, just limiting behaviour of trig functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to complement the previous answers, here is the graph of the function:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No, this function (call it $g$) is not, in fact, constant.

One way to see this is to check a couple inputs: we have $$g(0)=0.01338780219...\quad\mbox{but}\quad g(1)=0.64912088423...,$$ according to the all-knowing Google. Given how far apart these are, I suspect you may have just chosen very unlucky inputs.

But there's a more mathematical way to see this - in particular, one which doesn't require us to check values of $g$, which is extremely hard to do by hand. Namely, look at the derivative, which by the chain rule is $$g'=(\cos\cos\tan\cos\sin x)(-\sin\tan\cos\sin x)(\sec^2\cos\sin x)(-\sin\sin x)(\cos x).$$ Each of the functions $\sin,\cos,\tan,\sec^2$ is *countable-to-one* - for each $r$ there are at most countably many $x$ such that $f(x)=r$. Since the whole expression is zero exactly when one of the factors is zero and the composition of countable-to-one functions is countable to one (exercise), this means that there are only countably many $x$ for which $g'=0$; this means $g$ is not constant (since otherwise its derivative would be $0$ everywhere).

---

This is ignoring one small subtlety - namely, that $\sec^2$ and $\tan$ are not defined everywhere. But this turns out not to matter: $\sec^2$ and $\tan$ are defined on all but countably many inputs, and so we still get that $g'$ is defined and nonzero on most inputs.

Answer (score 1):

At $x=.1$ it is $.030305..$ but at $x=.2$ it's $.078611..$ (note using radians here.)